# grunt file glob file extension pattern

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, file-globs

I have a grunt task to traverse a folder structure for all `jpg`, `jpeg` and `png` files.  Is there an easier way to do this compared to

```
images : {
    expand : true,
    flatten : true,
    cwd : "develop/",
    src : ["modules/**/*.jpg", "modules/**/*.jpeg", "modules/**/*.png"],
    dest : "build/resources/img/"
},
```

According to the documentations, the `{ .. }` bracket for a file allows multiple options to be compared with for the containing files.  However, the following do not work for `src` array values:

```
"modules/**/*{jpg, jpeg, png}"
"modules/**/*.{jpg, jpeg, png}"
"modules/**/*{.jpg, .jpeg, .png}"
```

and so therefore I was forced to do a straight glob pattern for each file extension

Comment: Try removing the extra spaces after the comma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's extra spaces after the commas in your expression.

This should do it: `"modules/**/*.{jpg,jpeg,png}"`